# directory of jsons to df with pathlib

Tags: python, json, pandas

I've got a set of jsons in a directory that I'm trying to loop through and read to Pandas df with `pathlib.Path('my_jsons_dir').iterdir()`

The case for a single file works great

```
json_path = pathlib.Path('my_json_path')
dict_single = json.loads(json_path.read_bytes())
df_single = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(pd.json_normalize(dict_single), orient='columns')
```

But the loop burps...

```
file_paths = pathlib.Path(file_dir)
data = []

for file in file_paths.iterdir():
    if file.is_file():
        dict = json.loads(file.read_bytes())
        df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(pd.json_normalize(dict), orient='columns')
        data.append(df)
```

error message

```
JSONDecodeError                           Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[34], line 8
      6 for file in file_paths.iterdir():
      7     if file.is_file():
----> 8         dict = json.loads(file.read_bytes())
      9         df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(pd.json_normalize(dict), orient='columns')
     10         data.append(df)

File c:\Users\mdw0523\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\json\__init__.py:346, in loads(s, cls, object_hook, parse_float, parse_int, parse_constant, object_pairs_hook, **kw)
    341     s = s.decode(detect_encoding(s), 'surrogatepass')
    343 if (cls is None and object_hook is None and
    344         parse_int is None and parse_float is None and
    345         parse_constant is None and object_pairs_hook is None and not kw):
--> 346     return _default_decoder.decode(s)
    347 if cls is None:
    348     cls = JSONDecoder

File c:\Users\mdw0523\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\json\decoder.py:337, in JSONDecoder.decode(self, s, _w)
    332 def decode(self, s, _w=WHITESPACE.match):
    333     """Return the Python representation of ``s`` (a ``str`` instance
    334     containing a JSON document).
    335 
    336     """
--> 337     obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
...
    354 except StopIteration as err:
--> 355     raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
    356 return obj, end

JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

It looks like a simple typing thing, but don't understand why `dict = json.loads(file.read_bytes())` isn't working the same way as it was in the single-file case
`libpath` preferred to `os` due to need for working flexibly across mac/win

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out error was caused by one of the files which contained no text. This question can be closed.